# Bilateral Stabilization

Tags: humanoid

I'm starting out in more complex robotics, which in this case includes the bilateral stabilization of a humanoid robot.

I know that when a human walks, his/her pelvis moves in correspondence, which allows for a basic stabilization when being on one leg in between steps.

I'm wondering about how to replicate this type of effect in a humanoid robot.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Dimitry M, but I'm afraid that questions like this really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. Also, the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) has good advice on how to write a good question. If you edit your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you.

Comment: Hi @dimitry M.  Here are a few topics for you to research,

In robotics there are two types of stability: static and dynamic.

Also read about support polygons.  

Note that the smallest polygon of support contains 3 points. Since humans and humanoid robots have only 2 legs, we have dynamic, not static stability when standing.   I hope this gets you on your way to reframing your question!